# Names for split Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, terminology

Do any of the simply connected simple Lie groups of the split real classical Lie algebras have names other than “the universal cover of _”?

Comment: Spin? (And of course SL and Sp.)

Comment: None of those are simply connected.

Comment: @DanielSebald The spin group ( as discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group ) is definitely simply connected for $n > 2$.

Comment: That only applies to the definite spin groups. The split spin groups have fundamental groups of order 2 for $n>5$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453602/names-for-split-lie-groups#comment1173561_453602), I see, you mean that the real Lie groups are not simply connected.  As algebraic groups, they are called simply connected, which is what I meant to [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453602/names-for-split-lie-groups#comment1173555_453602); but I now see that it is not what you were asking.  Sorry!

Comment: In a sense, the title is slightly confusing, since "split" is an inessential restriction: the topic is really *"Names for universal covers of classical Lie groups"*.